# Create Team, 400 Bad Request, Required functionality is not supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a Microsoft Teams team in Migration mode via the Graph API. However I get a 400 response that I can't figure out. The query is shared in the link below.

[Shared Query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=teams&method=POST&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&requestBody=eyJAbWljcm9zb2Z0LmdyYXBoLnRlYW1DcmVhdGlvbk1vZGUiOiJtaWdyYXRpb24iLCJ0ZW1wbGF0ZUBvZGF0YS5iaW5kIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9ncmFwaC5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2JldGEvdGVhbXNUZW1wbGF0ZXMoJ3N0YW5kYXJkJykiLCJkaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6IlNsYWNrTWlncmF0aW9uVGVzdCIsImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjoidGVzdGluZyIsImNyZWF0ZWREYXRlVGltZSI6IjIwMjEtMDEtMTRUMDA6MDA6MDAuMDAwWiJ9)

For those that don't want to view it that way, here is my request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams
Authorization: Bearer ...
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "@microsoft.graph.teamCreationMode": "migration",
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates(\u0027standard\u0027)",
  "displayName": "SlackMigrationTest",
  "description": "testing slack migrations",
  "createdDateTime": "2021-01-14T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I created this based on the microsoft doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams#request-create-a-team-in-migration-state).

The reponse I get is:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Required functionality is not supported.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-20T15:51:21",
      "request-id": "dc4189cf-db4a-4a60-a271-f63b5d759a05",
      "client-request-id": "dc4189cf-db4a-4a60-a271-f63b5d759a05"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure its something obvious that I'm missing but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried the above call, its throwing me HTTP 400 (thats ok, i can try to tweak the payload to see if it helps) as described in the documentation and not HTTP 405 what you see above. Make sure you logged into a user who has necessary permissions/roles and try making the same API call.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using the User Context token and trying to make the call. This API call only works in Application context as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

So use [Client Credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and set Application permissions and then make a call.

As you can see below, it worked for me with App token.
[image]

You cannot test it in graph explorer because the Graph Explorer gets user token.

Comment: Using an application token rather than a user token worked, after doing this I thought I had more issues because the response body was empty in my application, it turns out the details for the create team come in the response headers instead for this request for some strange reason. - Just thought I'd mention it for anyone else that comes across that. Many thanks!